# What is the best way to run JavaScript in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, json, dwr

I looking for the best way to obtain JSON data, that polling from server to JS (generated by DWR) in the client-side. So I going to make Java-client for it. Any ideas and advices about it are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Primary goal - to understand how I can intercept JSON data transmitted from server (like in the Firebug). On the server-side - DWR (JSP pages), on the client-side - JS that generated by server. This scheme works with long-polling.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me but I don't think your question is clear.

Comment: so you want an ability to process JSON in java, is that correct? if thats the case, checkout http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: I've updated a question. Thanks for your notes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a JavaScript implementation for Java called [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) (from Mozilla). I think it's in the JDK since version 1.6. You can run JavaScript with it in your Java program ([here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/RunningScriptswithJavaScriptEngine.htm) is a small tutorial for it, you will find more on google).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a JSON parsing library for Java like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) ?

Or you could make a webclient since this is obviously the purpose of the generated JS.